# Disable-PnpDevice failed and device status is 'Error'

Tags: windows, powershell, audio, windows-10

What I'm trying to do is disable the audio card then enable it:

First, disable the audio device

```
Get-PnpDevice -FirendlyName 'xxx' -PresentOnly | Disable-PnpDevice
```

Nothing has returned.

I checked the control panel and the target device is still enabled, and run `Get-PnpDevice` the status is 'Error'.

How can I get more detail about the error? How to disable the device correctly?

Comment: have you started powershell as admin?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes

Comment: split get and disable device in 2 commands and check which fails

Comment: @magicandre1981 it's disable

Comment: which HW ID does get return?

Comment: @magicandre1981no returned id

Comment: ok, so this is the issue. Is the friendly name correct?

Comment: @magicandre1981of course. how the status is 'error' if not correct.

Comment: @GZXue Provide the complete error message.